# What is the point of client-side captcha verification?

Tags: spam, captcha, bot

I have seen dozens of client-side captcha verification on github and considering it is just a matter of time to make it totally useless, what are the purposes of these? Are there any justifications that I don't see? Maybe, the only thing I can think of is to only send the hash of the captcha to the client-side but I could not see any hash-wise implementations in any of these projects. Briefly, excluding "easier to implement" argument, why would someone prefer client-side captcha verification against server-side one?

Comment: *"it is just a matter of time to make it totally useless"* - maybe this is the point then? Make the attacker invest time first? Maybe the site is not worth the effort, maybe the attacker is not actually skilled enough ... .

Comment: I don't think it is client-side, is it? I was under the impression that the server still knows the correct result and the client sends it using the API.